# How to build a .jar file

Tags: java, jar

Please note I do **not** mean building a .jar file using an IDE such as eclipse.

What I'd like to accomplish is creating a .jar using my program. For example the user enters some information and then click "Build" and a .jar file would be built and would have that information that the user enters.

I was thinking about maybe saving a file with a .java extension and writing lines of code to that file and then use cmd to build a .jar file.

That's not really the solution I want to use as I'm sure there is a better way to do it.

Comment: If you need to compile, look into class `JavaCompiler`. Otherwise, `jar` is just a `zip`.

Comment: I would rather think in external configuration files: you could have 1 jar (above all...), that would work with a properties file, or XML configuration the user can specify. I fyou add details on the problem you try to solve, you might get more specific advices.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The `jar` spec has additional restrictions on the order in which files have to be placed into the archive, so not every `zip` utility will work.

Comment: @chrylis Interesting. So find out what those restrictions are and follow them.

Comment: take a look at the [javaCompiler tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) and the [jar utils](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The [JAR spec is here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) but doesn't mention the ordering restrictions, which *might* have been removed. They existed originally to support quicker applet loading by requiring the manifest and maybe some related files to be located at the front so a streaming download could start unpacking it and setting up the runtime.

Comment: @chrylis I'm not even sure I knew that; do you have a reference? A quick glance at [the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) wasn't enlightening, but it's quite possible I missed it.

Comment: @DaveNewton The wiki ([lol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format))) says so, but yeah couldn't find in spec either.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at
https://github.com/Quillion/Engine/blob/master/jarIt.bat
This is what I use to pack my jars. You can also learn more about it by reading documentation

Comment: Looks little complicated. I need also to build java project on mac os. Any suggestion or link

Comment: @NikolaLukic if you are using gradle you can just use gradle task to build it, but if you are not using gradle then the link I posted can get it accomplished, just make a few changes to fit your mac and you are set